# mysql вложенные запросы update и insert

Tags: mysql

Необходимо обновить базу данных. Есть связанная таблица A и B.

В таблице А следующие колонки:

```
a.id,
a.email,
a.b_id (может быть пустой)
```

В таблице B:

```
b.id,
b.email,
```

Нужно обновить все a.b_id и подставить туда значения b.id, если совпадает email в обоих таблицах. Если не существует записи b.email, а.email существует, то необходимо создать b.email с такой почтой

Comment: одним запросом обновить одну таблицу и внести данные в другую нельзя. пишите процедуру или воспользуйтесь удобным для вас ЯП

Comment: @splash58 или просто сделать два запроса :-)

Comment: Кстати, да. Не подумал